# An error happened during Keycloak initialization

Tags: angular, firefox, promise, single-sign-on, keycloak

Only in Firefox web browser I am getting the below error message:

```
Error: "Uncaught (in promise): An error happened during Keycloak initialization."
```

Comment: mostly this error happen due to CORS. so please disable CORSE in browser.